# python Generic Type Hints + user-defined container + constraining to Types implementing __add__ method

Tags: python, type-hinting, abstract-data-type, generic-type-argument

I want to implement in python 3.8 a Liste class the Lisp way with head and tail, car(), cdr() and nil. I want to define a generic type accepting objects of Type T in the Liste.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')
class Liste(Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self, h: T, t: Liste[T]) -> None:
        self.head = h
        self.tail = t

    @staticmethod
    def nil() -> Liste[T]:
        return Liste(None, None)

    def est_vide(self) -> bool:
        return (self.head is None) and (self.tail is None)
    def cdr(self)->Liste[T]:
        if self.tail is None: return Liste.nil()
        else: return  self.tail

    def sum(self)->T:
        if self.est_vide():
            return 0
        else:
            return self.head + self.cdr().sum()
```

I had a very good moment with type hints all along. But mypy points 4 errors

```
liste_sof.py:13: error: Argument 1 to "Liste" has incompatible type "None"; expected "T"
liste_sof.py:13: error: Argument 2 to "Liste" has incompatible type "None"; expected "Liste[T]"
liste_sof.py:23: error: Incompatible return value type (got "int", expected "T")
liste_sof.py:25: error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("T")
Found 4 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Problem 1 is to be able to specify that I expect T objects that implement the `__add__` method. I don't know how to do that.

Problem 2 is to deal with the special `Liste.nil()` empty object of my class.

Comment: Problem 3 is to find the Empty object of the class T implementing the `__add__` method. For str, i want "", for int or floats, 0 would do

Comment: separate problems should be separate questions

Comment: You'll need to use `Optional` for `t` and `h`, and you could use a Protocol to describe the structural type "supports add". There is no clean way to find "an empty object" for all types that support add. So, instead of a generic protocol, you may just use restricted typevar for the types you want to support.

Comment: Honestly, this class will be very academic. Your implementation of `sum` will not work for large lists, for example. Python is not Lisp, they are quite different languages. In python, you should use iteration not recursion to implement this. Also, you don't want to support `str`, because that just creates a hidden quadratic time algorithm when a linear time algorithm for concatenating `str` objects is trivial in Python

Answer (score 2):

Mypy is complaining because you need to use `Optional` if you want `h` or `t` to be able to be `None`, otherwise, you are implying *everything* must be `None`, which isn't generic.

You can use structural typing with a `Protocol` to express "has `__add__`".

Finally, there is no clean way to get "the empty object". For built-in types, `type(self)()` may work, but honestly, I would just force the API take the initial value.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Generic, Protocol, Optional


T = TypeVar('T')

class SupportsAdd(Protocol[T]):
    def __add__(self: T, other: T) -> T:
        ...

A = TypeVar('A', bound=SupportsAdd)

class Liste(Generic[A]):
    def __init__(self, h: Optional[A], t: Optional[Liste[A]]) -> None:
        self.head = h
        self.tail = t

    @staticmethod
    def nil() -> Liste[A]:
        return Liste(None, None)

    def est_vide(self) -> bool:
        return (self.head is None) and (self.tail is None)

    def cdr(self)->Liste[A]:
        if self.tail is None: return Liste.nil()
        else: return  self.tail

    def sum(self, init: A) -> A:
        if self.head is None or self.tail is None:
            return init
        else:
            return self.head + self.cdr().sum(init)
```

As I stated in the comments, this class is very academic, you probably shouldn't actually use it. It will be inefficient. At the very least, you shouldn't use recursion for `sum`.

Comment: it IS academic indeed with no efficiency in mind yet. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: I guess `class Liste(Generic[A]):` instead of `class Liste(Generic[T]):` in your proposition ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @smeden whoops. Yes.