# mypy: Unsupported left operand type error when adding two strings together

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a function that looks like this:

```
from typing import Sequence

def test(a: Sequence[str]):
    b: Sequence[str] = ["test1"]
    c: Sequence[str] = a+b

test(["test2"])
```

mypy returns the error `Unsupported left operand type for + ("Sequence[str]")` in the line where c is defined. How can I rewrite this function to make it work?

Comment: Use `list[str]` instead of `Sequence[str]`?

Comment: Indeed, using `List` if it is possible makes things much more simple and clear.

Answer (score 0):

The [doc for `typing.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence) :

> A generic version of `collections.abc.Sequence`.

The [doc for `collections.abc.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) speaks not of `__add__` (the protocol method for addition).
The [recap table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) neither.

It needs to be implemented, like suggested in this answer to [python Generic Type Hints + user-defined container + constraining to Types implementing **add** method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64141594/11384184). Here is the [MyPy doc on protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html).

I tried something along that way, but it sill not typechecks :

```py
from typing import Sequence, Protocol, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')
class SelfAddable(Protocol[T]):
    def __add__(self: T, other: T) -> T:
        ...


X = TypeVar('X')
class AddableSequence(Sequence[X], SelfAddable):
    pass


def foo(a: AddableSequence[str]):
    b: AddableSequence[str] = ["test1"]
    c: AddableSequence[str] = a+b


foo(["test2"])

# reveal_type(list.__add__)
# Revealed type is "def [_T] (builtins.list[_T`1], builtins.list[_T`1]) -> builtins.list[_T`1]"
```

```
so70940005.py:16: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[str]", variable has type "AddableSequence[str]")
so70940005.py:20: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "List[str]"; expected "AddableSequence[str]"
```